# How to add custom permission for a node?

Tags: users

Is there any way to add custom permissions for a node?

Here is the requirement: I have a node where I have to set 2 permission, view & subscribe. View permission I can use the default content view permission. But how can I introduce a new permission for subscribe?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Are you asking for a module you are writing? In that case, we need to see the code you wrote so far.

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative is to use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, and create a rule that is a variation of the rule mentioned in my answer to the question aboutr "[How to make the permissions of a module more granular?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182326/how-to-make-the-permissions-of-a-module-more-granular/182327#182327)".

The variation in your case will be something like so:

- Use the path specific to the node of your case.
- Adapt the "Rules Action" to fit your needs.

You may also want to add some "Rules condition(s)" related to the "role" that is required to allow actions like edit, delete, etc. If you have multiple actions like that, you either build one such rule for each action, or you use the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module to make it all fit in a single rule. Obviously, this approach does not "introduce" a new permission that can be assigned by an admin (which is not a requirement either in the original version of this question, right?).

Comment: Main challenge is,I have to introduce this new permission in the content access window of the page. From there admin will assign the permission, like edit delete view...

Answer (score 0):

Permissions are created using [`hook_permission`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7):

```
function hook_permission() {
  return array(
    'administer my module' => array(
      'title' => t('Administer my module'),
      'description' => t('Perform administration tasks for my module.'),
    ),
  );
}
```

And checked with [`user_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_access/7):

```
if (user_access('administer my module')) {
  // Access granted
}
```

Comment: Hi @clive : the problem here is I want to execute the permission for individual contents of the same content type