# Show blocks based on parent URL context

Tags: 7, blocks

We are looking for a way to show banners on pages based on their URL parent. There are multiple banners in use, and each page should display a banner based on its parent page. We want to build this into the theme, if at all possible.

So, for the Programs section, the Programs banner should display. However, within Programs there are named Programs with their own banners, such as "Great Program" and "Program For Winners" which each have their own sub-pages. When on those sub-pages, we want only the banner for the specific program to show.

**/programs** - Show Programs banner (top-level parent)

**/programs/all** - Show Programs banner

**/programs/great-program** - Show Great Program banner (second-level parent)

**/programs/great-program/about-great-program** - Show Great Program banner

**Note**: I'm using D7, and probably using blocks, maybe [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). Open to all suggestions.

Comment: (Ack, did I really?) D7, and probably using blocks, maybe views. Open to all suggestions.

Comment: Add an attachment to each view (at top). The attachment either has a hardcoded image, or it has its context set up the parent tree one level and has some contextual image link, or it takes its context from the current level if deep down. This way you run the content display entirely with Views. Or use the normal node display and embed the view for the banner as a block or a node embedded view (DS, EVA etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd implement those banners via blocks, then you might be able to get it to work using the [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> The Rules block visibility module allows [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) components to be used to control block visibility. This provides Drupal administrators and developers extreme flexibility in controlling when blocks should be displayed on their websites, in addition to the default visibility options provided by Drupal.
>
> The general idea is that if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility, so the possibilities are limitless.
>
> Need to show a block only for users registered more than a month ago?
>
> Perhaps you have a block that must be shown only between 8am-5pm on weekdays?
>
> What about displaying or hiding a block based on current weather conditions?
>
> All of this can be done by using Rules block visibility.

With that, and as per the "*if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility*" above, you've reduced your question to making [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) intercept the various URLs corresponding to each of those banners.

If you're not familiar with how to do that with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), then have a look at my answer to the question "[How to make the permissions of a module more granular?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182326)" (and pay attention to the regex-expression included in the sample rule I included there).