# Is there a D7 equivalent to the Unlimited Field module?

Tags: 7, entities

I need a field allowing either a numeric value or "unlimited".

The [Unlimited Number](https://www.drupal.org/project/unlimited_number) module is exactly what I want, but it's D8-only.

Is there a way to do the same thing in D7?

Comment: I am not able to understand. From your question title it looks you need unlimited field, if so, kindly check [Field collection module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) or [Field Group module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group), when you set up, it has a option to chose number of field or chose unlimited fields. May be this may help.

Comment: The OP is talking about the _Unlimited number_ module, which allows the users to select a number from a option list or a special number with a specific meaning. It's not about entering multiple entries for the same field.

Answer (score 0):

To implement ***a field allowing either a numeric value or "unlimited"*** in D7, you can define such field using the desired widget (like a textfield maybe?). And then use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to validate the actual data that is entered before the entity (like a node or user where you use that field?) is saved (created or updated).

Some more details about the validation part of such rules to be created:

1. Add the appropriate validations you want within the Rules **Conditions**.
2. You may want to specify multiple conditions and combine them with an "OR", eg to validate that the value entered is either the string "unlimited", or a digit equal to "0", "1", "2", "3" or "4".
3. If you have lots of allowed digits (say dozens), just use an appropriate regular expression (instead of a loooong list of digits).

Have a look at my answer to "[How to make the permissions of a module more granular?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182326/how-to-make-the-permissions-of-a-module-more-granular/182327#182327)", which you can use as examples of what might be needed to implement *Rules conditions* as in bullets "2." or "3." above.

Of course you'd also have to pick the most appropriate **Rules Event** for this rule to be triggered. But there are quite a few, straight forward, events you can pick from (depending on where exactly you want to use this field), just to mention a few:

- Before inserting a new node (optionally limited to content type ABC). E.g. if your field is used to "Store the maximum speed on highways in country X".
- Before saving an update to a user profile. E.g. if your field is used to "Store the duration (in days, months or years) of some type of membership subscription".

And your **Rules Action** is probably just a simple "Drupal set message". Though I can think of honeypot-scenarios where some specific values that got selected could result in a rules action like "block this user".

If you want even more granularity, you might also want to have a look at [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional), which allows for using "Rules Conditions" within "Rules Actions". Refer to my answer to "[How to prevent a node being saved when using the Rules module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/114955/how-to-prevent-a-node-being-saved-when-using-the-rules-module/178623#178623)" for an illustration of using this module.

Comment: Pierre, thanks for the detailed answer. I haven't used Rules yet, but I'll certainly give it a look. I've since thought of a different way I could get what I want: with conditional fields. I'll report back either way, so that other D7 users can find a solution.