# Restrict a role to administer certain vocabularies and terms, and remove the access to creating vocabularies

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I gave to users the *Administer vocabularies and terms* permission to let them access the page on *admin/structure/taxonomy*, but I want to restrict the access to that page to certain vocabularies.

The only issue that remains is the *Add vocabulary* permission that comes with *Administer vocabularies and terms*.

How can I restrict users from creating/editing some vocabularies and still  giving the permission to maintain taxonomy terms in other vocabularies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"***Creating a new vocabulary***" is what you do using the URL `admin/structure/taxonomy/add`, while "***Editing existing vocabularies***" (say with machine name `demotags`) is done using the URL `admin/structure/taxonomy/demotags/edit`.

A possible solution to "*restrict*" access to these URLs (which seems to be the missing piece you are looking for) is to use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module for this. To do so, have a look at my answer to the question "[How to make the permissions of a module more granular?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182326/how-to-make-the-permissions-of-a-module-more-granular)". It includes a rule (in rules export format), which you should be able to use if you apply these minor tunings to it:

- Check the Rules Condition about which roles this validation should be applied for (if any, if not remove that condition).
- Adapt the Rules Condition with the URLs containing `visitors` (to match the taxonomy related URLs like in my first paragraph).
- You probably don't need the Rules Condition with the "regex" in it (you only have a few URLs to be validated). In that case, you don't need the "OR" part either.
- Review the Rules Action (the message you want to show, and the redirect you want to force).

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new permission called for example 'Add new vocabulary'

```
 /**
  * Implements hook_permission().
  */
   function YOUR-CUSTOM-MODULE-NAME_permission() {
      $permissions = array(
        'add new vocabulary' => array(
          'title' => t('Add new vocabulary'),
        ),
      );
      return $permissions;
    }
```

2. Alter menu admin/struture/taxonomy/add 'access arguments'

```
 
  /**
  * Implements hook_menu_alter().
  */
   function YOUR-CUSTOM-MODULE-NAME_menu_alter(&$items) {
   $items['admin/structure/taxonomy/add']['access arguments'] = 
    array('add new vocabulary');
   }
```

3. From admin/people/permissions you will find your new permission 'Add new vocabulary' under your YOUR-CUSTOM-MODULE-NAME, and give it only to your desired roles.