# How can I give paid access to content?

Tags: views, commerce, rules, taxonomy-terms

I am looking to manage user access to website content using Rules and the suggested access control module i.e. ACL, TAC etc.

There 3 levels of access to manage:

- Unregistered - No access to any Course Content
- Registered - Access to certain Preview nodes (see Preview Module below)
- Paid - Access to the content to which they have paid (as well as Preview nodes)

### Unregistered

- Unregistered users will have no access to any Course Content nodes
- However there may be pages on the site (Cookie, Terms etc.) which anonymous will need access to to keep the site functioning during registration/payment etc.

### Registered Users / Preview Module

- For each Course, 1 or more Modules (taxonomy term) will be marked as a Preview Module
- Preview Modules are identified by the term with a boolean check box: field_module_preview
- This should allow access to Registered uses to access the nodes within this Module.

Content types: 
Course – setup as a product
Content

Taxonomy:
Topic
Module

Example:

```
> Course
> - Module
> - - Topic
> - - - Course Content NO Access
> - Module (Preview checked)
> - - Topic 
> - - - Course Content: Access
> - - - Course Content: Access
> - - Topic 
> - - - Course Content: Access
> - - - Course Content: Access
> - Module
> - - Topic
> - - - Course Content NO Access
```

### Paid Access

- Payment processing will be carried out using Drupal Commerce and PayPal. The setup of this is not required. Drupal install will be supplied with Commerce and product types setup.
- Once a course is paid, then access is granted to the entire Course and all its nodes

I have tried to integrate rules but no hope to make it working.

Can anyone help me to apply this scenario in my drupal 7?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Organic groups using organic groups access module solves this use case. The complexity arises with creating group memberships to courses based on payment, but that is do-able with some glue / custom code.

Comment: Hi @mradcliffe,  Thank you for your answer. I was thinking in same of choosing OG. But i want this with current taxonomy structure. So the taxonomy term reference given to course content type and course content type having product entity reference. I am very much confuse at one point. When User checkout process gets completed, I was setting up component to fetch ordered entity. But some how i am not getting the proper inputs in components.

Comment: Seriously, I can't believe that stack exchange can have this kind of limitation.. I have asked a simple normal question and added each and every possible detail.. I will find it by my self it ok. Thank you.

Comment: Let me know your email id. We can discuss on that.. I will give each and every detail.. Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get this to work using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, using a variation of the rule shown/explained in the answer to "[How to make the permissions of a module more granular?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182326/how-to-make-the-permissions-of-a-module-more-granular/182327#182327)". I.e in your case:

- you can use the same Rules Event (Drupal is initializing), which to my knowledge is the only Rules Event you can use for this (for any other Rules Event you're just "too late", i.e. the content is already being displayed).
- you can perform similar Rules Actions (to perform an appropriate redirect and display a message that fits your needs).
- you should use one or more of these Rules Conditions (combined with "OR", not with "AND"!):

  - check if the current user's role is "anonymous".
  - related to your field `field_module_preview`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use roles and permissions based on roles.  Two roles you get without doing any thing:

- Anonymous User
- Authenticated User

Use the first for Unregistered and the second for Registered.  You can create a Paid Role for registered users that pay up.

You can use the rules module to add/remove the Paid role when users pay and lapse payment.

Comment: I am following same way. You can see my above comment.  I am getting stuck when retrieving entities from course content. there might be n number of line items which is taxonomy term behaves as a node. So i need to give paid role permission to each and every node. But its not actually happening. I spend my two full days. But i felt that i lost somewhere. So posted here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a per-configured package in Drupal known as [Telekonsum](https://www.drupal.org/project/telekonsum) . 
by default this has the possibility to sale the user roles. I hope this will helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help mukesh.. I need rules to be compatible to the current taxonomy i have setup. I don't want to use any other options.

Comment: Oh ok!. You just install and take a lok on telekonsum. form this you may gain any ideas for your requirement.